# How to convert arrays of numbers into a matrix in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, matrix

I have a two simple arrays of numbers, representing the cartesian position of an object.

```
a = [3, 4]
b = [8, 5]
```

I want to check if "a" and "b" are beside each other. I would like to convert the two into a matrix and perform a subtractions of the two positions, and then check if the absolute value of either element is "1".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at Ruby's built-in [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find anything that can convert my array into a 1 x 2 matrix. I tried to coerce it to a Matrix with a.coerce(Matrix), but I get "uninitialized constant Matrix'

Comment: The second method in the documentation ([`Matrix[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html%23method-c-5B-5D)) tells you what to do. Each argument becomes a row of the matrix, so if you want a matrix with one row with the values from the array `a`, do  `my_matrix = Matrix[a]`.

Comment: I have tried that but I get uninitialized constant Matrix. Is there a special library I have to require or gem to install?

Comment: You have to require Matrix. `require "matrix"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the uninitialized constant error because you first need:

```
require 'matrix'
```

Then you could just:

```
Matrix[a,b]
```

Sample interactive output:

```
irb(main):011:0> require 'matrix'
=> true
irb(main):012:0> Matrix[a,b]
=> Matrix[[3, 4], [8, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `Matrix` class methods is justified here. The only method that would be marginally useful is [Matrix#-](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-2D), but to  use that you need to convert your arrays to `Matrix` objects, apply `Matrix#-`, then convert the resultant matrix object back to an array to determine if the absolute value of any element equals one (whew!). I'd just do this:

```
def adjacent?(a,b)
  a.zip(b).any? { |i,j| (i-j).abs == 1 }
end

adjacent?([3, 4], [8, 5]) #=> true
adjacent?([3, 7], [8, 5]) #=> false
adjacent?([3, 7], [2, 5]) #=> true
```

For the first example:

```
a = [3, 4]
b = [8, 5]
c = a.zip(b)
  #=> [[3, 8], [4, 5]]
c.any? { |i,j| (i-j).abs == 1 }
  #=> true
```

The last statements determines if either of the following is `true`.

```
(3-8).abs == 1
(4-5).abs == 1
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well. Thanks!